# The type or namespace name doesn't exist in the namespace etc

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference

Visual Studio 2012.

I have two projects A and B. A is the console application. The default namespace of A is "PayT'. B is class library type, the sAssembly name' is 'RetentionPolicyManager', the default namespace of B is 'RetentionPolicyManager'.

Now in project A, I added reference of B that is RetentionPolicyManager.dll to it.

In one class of A, there is one line:

```
using PayT.RetentionPolicyManager;
```

However I always got the error when I rebuild the solution:

> *The type or namespace name 'RetentionPolicyManager' does not exist in the namespace 'PayT'(are you missing an assembly reference?)*

If I don't build the solution, it seems to be okay and no error.

Comment: Have you tried just `using RetentionPolicyManager`?

Comment: It is still wrong, actually if I type PayT., the intelsense does show 'RetentionPolicyManager'.

Comment: "If I don't build the solution, it seems to be okay and no error." That's the thing about compile errors...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced same issue some months ago. The problem was **both projects didn't target the same platform**, i.e. the console application targeted `.Net framework 4.0 Client Profile` while the library targeted `full .Net framework 4.0`.

Fixed by targeting full .Net 4.0 framework for both projects.

Comment: I used .net 4.0 in one project, .net 4.5 in the other project. Now I applied the same .net 4.0 to both of them. Now the library project's reference could not be found error(Metadata file could not found in B\bin\Debug, but it is there).

Comment: Which is 4.5, which is 4.0? Could you try specifying 4.5 for both?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an error that VS can spot at compile-time and not throw a seemingly unrelated error?

Comment: I wish I could +10 this. Although it didn't solved my problem, it guided me to the source. I would have lost days just to figure that the targeting platform could provoke this.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `RetentionPolicyManager` doesn't exist in `PayT` it is it's own namespace in a separate dll, you just need:

```
 using RetentionPolicyManager
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, it should be:

`using RetentionPolicyManager;`

Answer (score 0):

In `A` just use:

```
using RetentionPolicyManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

the namespace of B is `RetentionPolicyManager`, `PayT` is the namespace of the Assembly A. remove `PayT` from using statement.

```
using RetentionPolicyManager;
```